# Evil mode dot key and numeric commands

Tags: evil

I've been using Viper for countless years, and I'm trying to switch to Evil. One of the first things I noticed is that the dot 'do-again' key doesn't take any numeric arguments to the last command into account.

For example, if I type `2dw` to delete two words, and then `.` to delete two more words, the dot key only deletes one (i.e. only repeats `dw`).

Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this here.  That aside, this is the wrong place for bug reports, you should post them on https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues instead.

Comment: @wasamasa: I can reproduce the issue (`evil` version 1.2.10).  Interestingly, `2dw` then `.` does not work correctly, but `d2w` then `.` does work correctly.  I agree that it should be posted to `evil`'s issue tracker.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on the latest version?

Comment: I was using Evil 1.2.12 (from melpa), but with the version from git this bug is gone. Great!